# Conditional probability when flipping a random number $N$ of fair coins

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

> Suppose we flip a random number $N$ of fair coins, and the total
>   number of heads is $H$. If $P(N=n)=2^{-n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$, what is
>   $P(N=n\mid H=1)$?

---

My attempt: $$P(N=n\mid H=1)=\frac{P(H=1\mid N=n)P(N=n)} {P(H=1)}$$ by conditional probability. Now $P(H=1\mid N=n)=\dbinom{n} {1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2^n}$, but I don't know how to compute ${P(H=1)}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}P(H=1)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(H=1\mid N=n)P(N=n)\end{align}

Comment: Sorry it might sound stupid, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}=2$, which indicates something is wrong?

Comment: No, my bad. I corrected it.